# Можно заменить INSERT INTO на UPDATE через PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Можно заменить `INSERT INTO` на `UPDATE` через `PHP`?

```
INSERT INTO list (id, value) VALUES ('AU', 'Австралия');
INSERT INTO list (id, value) VALUES ('AT', 'Австрия');
INSERT INTO list (id, value) VALUES ('AZ', 'Азербайджан');
INSERT INTO list (id, value) VALUES ('AX', 'Аландские о-ва');
```

UPDATE
Нужно заполнить `ru` `where id`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38277/discussion-on-question-by-kyran---insert-into--update--php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str="INSERT INTO list (id, value) VALUES ('AU', 'Австралия');
INSERT INTO list (id, value) VALUES ('AT', 'Австрия');
INSERT INTO list (id, value) VALUES ('AZ', 'Азербайджан');
INSERT INTO list (id, value) VALUES ('AX', 'Аландские о-ва');";

print preg_replace('/INSERT INTO list \(id, value\) VALUES \((.*?), (.*?)\)/',
                   'update list set value=$2 where id=$1',
                   $str);
```

Или используете такую регулярку прямо на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hD5qJ4/1). В среднее окно вставляете свой текст, из нижнего забираете результат.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно зачем надо заморачиваться с PHP. Операция явно одноразовая и в данном случае проще все сделать через SQL.

1. Создать таблицу **list**.
2. Залить в него имеющийся дамп
3. Обновить данные в таблицы **country** с помощью подзапроса к таблице **list**
4. Удалить таблицу **list**

Запрос для обновления данных может быть следующим

```
UPDATE country SET RU = (SELECT value FROM list WHERE list.id=country.id)
```

Comment: UPDATE country join list using(id) SET country.RU = list.value